# Tracert first hop different subnet

Tags: routing, ipv4, tcp, subnet

Can someone enlighten me on how the below is possible?

---

I have a remote site, L2 connection to HQ. Clients are configured like this...

- Client (rc01) IP address 10.1.1.1/24
- Gateway 10.1.1.254/24 (The catch: I have no access or control of this device)

HQ Edge firewall details...

- internal 192.168.1.1/24
- external 100.1.0.1/30

HQ example server...let's call it hq01

- 192.168.1.2/24
- Gateway 192.168.1.1/24

---

When I run a tracert from rc01 -> hq01 the first response is from hq01. But if I do the reverse (hq01 -> rc01) the first response is from the internal interface of the hq firewall as expected.

How is rc01 finding hq01 without first going through a gateway?

Comment: because your gateway is a firewall, and it isn't messing with TTL. (firewalls are known to do this crap to "hide")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firewalls can be setup to not decrement the ttl(time to live) as a weak security feature, to make them invisible. This is the default on the ASA.

Explanation for your scenario,

The FW(10.1.1.254) has a interface in the server range 192.168.1.0/24. Then traceroute with ttl=1 will hit hq01 and get a response as FW delivers packet to directly connected subnet without decrementing the ttl.

In the reverse direction your server hq01 uses a real router, and sees it as the first hop, the FW is again hidden (no ttl decrement) and you see the pc next.

[Traceroute Overview](http://www.nanog.org/meetings/nanog47/presentations/Sunday/RAS_Traceroute_N47_Sun.pdf)